# How to reset webpage after altered content via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reset

I have a JS script that changes content of webpages. I use this script in the console in firebug. When i run the script again with some new data, the old stuff that was altered previously is still there.

How can i reset the whole the page to its original condition whenever i execute my script, so that the old script generated stuff gets replaced by the new one?

In have tried to do a refresh before the main function that changes the content, but the refresh is so slow that it deletes both the old altered content and the new.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? In particular: how are you changing the content of the page?

Comment: It's nothing special, it just changes the color and innerHTML of specific elements on the page.

Comment: Setting the `innerHTML` property of a DOM element would replace its entire contents, in which case your problem would not occur. To make your question answerable, you will have to make it more specific. It would help if you could post the script in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're just changing HTML then when first run the script you could do:

```
var originalHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Then when you're done and want to 'reset' just do:

```
document.body.innerHTML = originalHtml;
```

Comment: Incredible, so simple and easy. It works!
I was thinking of a much more complex solution than this simple solution :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make the page reload itself